# How to go through a String array and list all numbers in a new int Array and leave the words in the string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

So using java, my problem is that I have a .txt file with numbers and words separated by spaces and I want to create 2 arrays. Filling the first array with only the words and I want the new second array to have all numbers inserted as ints.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File inputFile = new File("numbersandwords.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(" ");
    String[] words = new String[20];
    int[] numbers = new int[20];
    int i = 0;

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        words[i] = scan.next();
        i++;
    }

    //Insert Code here

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));

   }
   }
```

So far I have words[] populated with all content of the txt file. but I'm not sure how to move the numbers in words[] to numbers[].

Also this is NOT homework. I'm doing this just for myself to learn java. I am going through a textbook that has programming questions, with no answers.

Any help for this would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have to take word one by one convert them in int check weather string or number then place them respective array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solution..

public class TestClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File inputFile = new File("numbersandwords.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(" ");
    String[] words = new String[20];
    int[] numbers = new int[20];
    int i = 0;
    int j=0;

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String s = scan.next();
        if (isInteger(s)) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
            i++;
        }else{
            words[j] = s;
            j++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try {
        int myInt = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());

this line has an error it says
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "angel"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at ProgProj57.TestClass.main(altyanswer.java:29)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
File inputFile = new File("d:\\data.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter(" ");
String[] words = new String[20];
String[] temp = new String[20];
int[] numbers = new int[20];
String regex = "[0-9]+";
int i = 0;
int j=0;

while (scan.hasNext()) {
    words[i] = scan.next();
    if(words[i].matches(regex)){
    numbers[j]=Integer.parseInt(words[i]);// extracting numbers only
    i--;   // skipping null value
    j++;

    }else{
        temp[i]=words[i];   // extracting words
    }
    i++;
}
words=temp;  // copy temp to words array

//Insert Code here

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

file contains:

```
345 hello this is 10 file handling 2 4 56 78 345
```

Output:

```
[hello, this, is, file, handling, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[345, 10, 2, 4, 56, 78, 345, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Note:** *make sure your array size in enough to hold the data from file*

**EDIT: To remove null and 0s from array.**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(temp,0, j-1)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers,0, i-1)));
```

output:

```
[hello, this, is, file, handling, 35chainatouwn]
[345, 10, 2, 4, 56]
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, but is there anyway with arrays, that the result doesn't have nulls or 0s?.

Comment: you can accept the answer if it worked for you. you can remove those part null or 0s

Comment: how do i do that? nevermind, figured it out and I accepted it

Comment: user `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)` methods

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
        words[i] = scan.next();
        number[i] = words[i].replaceAll("\\D+","");  //delete non-digits.

        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't move words from the word list to the number list. First check if the word you read is a number or a word, and then put it in the right list.

To check if a string is a number you can use:

```
String word = scan.next();
...
int i = Integer.valueOf(word);
```

If your string is not a number it will throw an exception, you must catch it. If your numbers have a floating point, use `Double` instead of `Integer`.

And don't use fixed size arrays, you don't know how many elements you will have. Use an `ArrayList`, you can append new elements on the fly.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
...
words.add("word");
```

Comment: When chacking if a string is a number. 
If i use int i = Integer.valueOf(“4711"); 
do I have to keep writing the number i want to check it against? so do the same for 1, 2 3 etc? or does 4711 cover all numbers? probably a silly question

Comment: I changed the example a little. You use the word you read from the file. If it is a number it will be saved in `i`. Otherwise you get a `NumberFormatException`.